# Merge two array of objects with common key using jq command

Tags: bash, jq

I have two datasets:

```
data1='[
    { "bookings": 2984, "timestamp": 1675854900 },
    { "bookings": 2967, "timestamp": 1675855200 }
]'

data2='[
    { "errors": 51, "timestamp": 1675854900 },
    { "errors": 90, "timestamp": 1675855200 }
]'
```

I want the output to be:

```
combined='[
    { "errors": 51, bookings: 2984, "timestamp": 1675854900 },
    { "errors": 90, bookings: 2967, "timestamp": 1675855200 }
]'
```

Can this be achieved by shell scripting and jq command?

Assume that timestamp will always be present and will always have a common value across two datasets. Even the order is same.

Comment: Do you _want_ an answer that uses the order guarantee to optimize performance, or is that just an FYI and an answer that doesn't rely on it would be acceptable as well?

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that the same timestamp will never be found twice in data1 / twice in data2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This last paragraph just caught my attention:

> Assume that timestamp will always be present and will always have a common value across two datasets. Even the order is same.

If this is truly the case then it is reasonable to assume that both arrays have the same length and their items are aligned respectively. Thus, there's no need to build up a hash-based `INDEX` as accessing the items by their numeric `keys` (positions within the arrays) can already be achieved in constant time.

```bash
jq -n --argjson data1 "$data1" --argjson data2 "$data2" '
  $data1 | [keys[] | $data2[.] + $data1[.]]
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "errors": 51,
    "timestamp": 1675854900,
    "bookings": 2984
  },
  {
    "errors": 90,
    "timestamp": 1675855200,
    "bookings": 2967
  }
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`JOIN` operation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) could do:

```bash
jq -n --argjson data1 "$data1" --argjson data2 "$data2" '
  [JOIN(INDEX($data1[]; .timestamp); $data2[]; .timestamp | @text; add)]
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "errors": 51,
    "timestamp": 1675854900,
    "bookings": 2984
  },
  {
    "errors": 90,
    "timestamp": 1675855200,
    "bookings": 2967
  }
]
```

---

> I'm getting this error: `jq: error: JOIN/4 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:   [JOIN(INDEX($data1[]; .timestamp); $data2[]; .timestamp | @text; add)] jq: 1 compile error`

You are probably using an older version of jq. `JOIN` and `INDEX` were introduced in jq 1.6. Either define them yourself by taking their definitions from [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L282), or take those definitions and modify them to fit your very use case (both work well with jq 1.5).

Definitions from source:

```bash
jq -n --argjson data1 "$data1" --argjson data2 "$data2" '
  def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
    reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row | idx_expr | tostring] = $row);
  def JOIN($idx; stream; idx_expr; join_expr):
    stream | [., $idx[idx_expr]] | join_expr;

  [JOIN(INDEX($data1[]; .timestamp); $data2[]; .timestamp | @text; add)]
'
```

Adapted to your use case:

```bash
jq -n --argjson data1 "$data1" --argjson data2 "$data2" '
  ($data1 | with_entries(.key = (.value.timestamp | @text))) as $ix
  | $data2 | map(. + $ix[.timestamp | @text])
'
```

Comment: Nice. I'm going to finish out the answer I have in-flight, but this is a lot cleaner.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `jq: error: JOIN/4 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:
  [JOIN(INDEX($data1[]; .timestamp); $data2[]; .timestamp | @text; add)]
jq: 1 compile error`

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you find `JOIN` a bit tricky to understand or use, then consider using `INDEX` for this type of problem.  In the present case, you could get away with a trivially simple approach, e.g.:

```
jq -n --argjson data1 "$data1"  --argjson data2 "$data2" '
  INDEX($data1[]; .timestamp) as $dict
  | $data2 | map( . + $dict[.timestamp|tostring])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to build a map from timestamps to error counts, and perform a lookup in it.

```
jq -n '
  input as $data1
| input as $data2
| ($data2
   | map({ "key": (.timestamp | tostring), "value": .errors }) 
   | from_entries
  ) as $errors_by_timestamp
| $data1 | map(.errors = $errors_by_timestamp[(.timestamp | tostring)])
' <<<"$data1 $data2"
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I have trying to this answer from AI since morning and finally it also gave me correct solution this time

```
#!/bin/bash

data1='[
    { "bookings": 2984, "timestamp": 1675854900 },
    { "bookings": 2967, "timestamp": 1675855200 }
]'

data2='[
    { "errors": 51, "timestamp": 1675854900 },
    { "errors": 90, "timestamp": 1675855200 }
]'

combined=$(jq -n --argjson d1 "$data1" --argjson d2 "$data2" '
  [ $d1, $d2 ] | transpose[] | group_by(.timestamp) | map(
    reduce .[] as $i ({}; . * $i)
  )
')

echo "$combined"
```

Just pasting it here for you guys in case you didn't think of this method

Comment: jq's implementation of `group_by` involves a sort, and so this solution is somewhat inefficient, especially as it also uses `transpose`.  jq's support for JSON objects yields very fast lookup times, and so using a JSON object as a dictionary has much to recommend it.  Indeed, a sort-free implementation of `group_by` could use JSON objects in this manner.